# Javascript/jQuery is escaping my escape

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

I am dynamically generating a form in a large application. I've extracted a very small section of the code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/zys3zthp/ (uses jquery)

```
var valuelists={};
var calcs={};
var valuelists = {"regType":{"":"","Attendee":"Attendee","Exhibitor":"Exhibitor"},"yesno":{"":"","Yes":"Yes","No":"No"},"state":{"":"","AL":"AL","AK":"AK","AZ":"AZ","AR":"AR","CA":"CA","CO":"CO","CT":"CT","DE":"DE","DC":"DC","FL":"FL","GA":"GA","HI":"HI","ID":"ID","IL":"IL","IN":"IN","IA":"IA","KS":"KS","KY":"KY","LA":"LA","ME":"ME","MD":"MD","MA":"MA","MI":"MI","MN":"MN","MS":"MS","MO":"MO","MT":"MT","NE":"NE","NV":"NV","NH":"NH","NJ":"NJ","NM":"NM","NY":"NY","NC":"NC","ND":"ND","OH":"OH","OK":"OK","OR":"OR","PA":"PA","RI":"RI","SC":"SC","SD":"SD","TN":"TN","TX":"TX","UT":"UT","VT":"VT","VA":"VA","WA":"WA","WV":"WV","WI":"WI","WY":"WY","AB":"AB","BC":"BC","MB":"MB","NB":"NB","NL":"NL","NT":"NT","NS":"NS","NU":"NU","ON":"ON","PE":"PE","QC":"QC","SK":"SK","YT":"YT"}};

function addslashes(string) {
    //return string;
    return string.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\').
        replace(/\u0008/g, '\\b').
        replace(/\t/g, '\\t').
        replace(/\n/g, '\\n').
        replace(/\f/g, '\\f').
        replace(/\r/g, '\\r').
        replace(/'/g, '\\\'').
        replace(/"/g, '\\"');
}

function printInput(field, value)
    {
        var output="";
        if (valuelists[field])
        {
            output= '<select data-field="' + field + '" style="width:50%" name="' + field + '"><option value=""></option>';
            for(var name in valuelists[field])
            {
                var label = valuelists[field][name];
                if (name!='')
                {
                    var selected="";
                    if (name==value)
                    {
                        selected=" selected='selected' ";
                    }
                    output+='<option value="' + addslashes(name) +  '" ' + selected + '>' + label + '</option>';
                }
            }
            output+= '</select>';   
        }
        else
        {
            var readonly="";
            if (calcs[field])
            {
                readonly = " readonly='readonly' ";
            }
            output = "<input data-field='" + field + "' style='width:50%' type='text' name='" + field + "' value=\"" + addslashes(value) + "\" " + readonly + ">";
        }
        return output;
    }
var output ="";
output+=printInput("state", "CA");
output+=printInput("field2", "hello \" world");

$('body').html(output);
```

Whats happening is I want the textbox value to be: hello " world
I want to do this because it's user data and it can be anything. So yes it can have single quotes or double quotes.

printInput("field2", "hello \" world");

My guess:
I think my addslashes is working but I think somewhere my escape character is getting escaped and thats how i'm ending up with the regular slash...

Comment: Sure would be easier to just insert the value directly with JS into the DOM object after the HTML is created rather than putting the value into HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution for this would be to check for double quotes and replace them by single quotes.

Comment: But, the OP is trying to faithfully reproduce the content which could be double quotes.

Comment: Thats a nice idea but I can't mess with user data, if they wrote in a title field "the javascript "pro"" then they wouldn't want it to display 'the javascript 'pro''.

Answer (score -1):

My coworker helped me out.

Here's the fix. This add addslashes replaces with the HTML entities which gets converted in the textbox (wouldn't have guessed that):

```
function addslashes(string) {
    //return string;
    return string.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\').
        replace(/\u0008/g, '\\b').
        replace(/\t/g, '\\t').
        replace(/\n/g, '\\n').
        replace(/\f/g, '\\f').
        replace(/\r/g, '\\r').
        replace(/'/g, '&#39;').
        replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

Comment: You don't need to add slashes, you need to escape the HTML.